# RESTful interface for C++/Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, rest, restlet

I want to integrate the RESTful-API in my Qt-Project.
I already read the example on [this](http://jgoday.wordpress.com/2009/04/13/rest-client-with-qt-45/) page, but this is only for receiving data from a RESTful-interface, not for sending new data to the server. In Java, I can use RESTlet for example, is there any possibility to use something like that for Qt, too?
Or is there even a simple way to send data from Qt to RESTful, for example when I create a XML before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since REST is just normal URL access, there's no reason you can't use the Qt HttpClient interfaces to talk to you backend Java REST interface.  You just have to make a determination to use XML or JSON - both have very capable libraries available, and both are just text interfaces.

Odd you ask, I'm in the middle of doing this very thing myself today - I'm implementing a JSON based REST interface in Java, and I'll wire up the plumbing to my Qt app shortly.

I'll make an effort to update this answer as I progress.

Comment: You likely want to use QNetworkAccessManager, the other stuff is deprecated :)